# Fibonacci Last Number

Tags: fibonacci

I have this part of my code done, and I am trying to get it to print just the last Fibonacci Number, not all of them. How should I go about doing this? I know that the whole program isn't completed yet, but I just need to know how to print the last number for instance, when you select choice 1, then type "30" for index you should only get an output of 832040 instead of every fibonacci number to 30. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This is a Fibonacci sequence generator");
    System.out.println("Choose what you would like to do");
    System.out.println("1. Find the nth Fibonacci number");
    System.out.println("2. Find the smallest Fibonacci number that exceeds user given value");
    System.out.println("3. Find the two Fibonacci numbers whose ratio is close enough to the golden number");

    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    int xPre = 0;
    int xCurr = 1;
    int xNew;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Enter the target index to generate (>1): ");
            int index = scan.nextInt();

            for (int i = 2; i<=index; i++)
            {xNew = xPre + xCurr;
            xPre = xCurr;
            xCurr = xNew;
        System.out.println("The " + index + "th number Fibonacci number is " + xNew);

} 
}}}
```

Comment: Why not just omit the print statement in the for loop and print the value of xCurr as the last expression in the program?

Comment: How would I do that though? I still need the print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically just modify the code as below

```
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        System.out.print("Enter the target index to generate (>1): ");
        int index = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 2; i<=index; i++)
        {xNew = xPre + xCurr;
        xPre = xCurr;
        xCurr = xNew;       
} 
System.out.println("The " + index + "th number Fibonacci number is " + xNew);
```

Since the xNew Variable is last modified to hold the value of the index ( eg - 30 ) it should show the final value as 832040 alone.